# TypeError: this.state.show is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React.js, and I am learning to create a navigation component that lets me clicked on the hamburger button to view the menu on mobile and table. It's saying that error message is on line 42

**Here's my request and how I am attempting to render the data:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dropdown from "../components/pages/dropdowns/dropdown.js";
import hamburger from "../components/images/menu.svg";



class Navigation extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                show: false
            }
        }

        toggleShow() {
            this.toggleShow = this.toggleShow.bind(this)
            this.hide = this.hide.bind(this)
            this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
        }

        hide(e) {
            if (e && e.relatedTarget) {
                e.relatedTarget.click();
            }
            this.setState({ show: false });
        }
```

---

```
  render() {
      return (
          <Router>
              <div className="FlexContainer NavbarContainer">
                  <div className="mobilecontainer LeftNav">
                      <h2 className="BrandName LeftNav mobileboxmenu inline">Kommonplaces</h2>
                      <div 
                      className="hamburger inlinev"  
                      onClick={this.toggleShow}  
                      onBlur={this.hide}>
                          <img alt="menubtn" src={hamburger}></img>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  {
                        this.state.show 
                    ( 
                        <ul className="NavBar">
                            <Dropdown/>    
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Host Your Space</Link></li>
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">About Us</Link></li>
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to0="/">Contact Us</Link></li>
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Sign Up</Link></li>
                            <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Login</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    )
                  }
               </div>
         </Router>
      );
    }
}
  export default Navigation;
```

**I get the following error:**

> TypeError: this.state.show is not a function

```
  39 |     className="hamburger inlinev"  
  40 |     onClick={this.toggleShow}  
  41 |     onBlur={this.hide}>
> 42 |         <img alt="menubtn" src={hamburger}></img>
     | ^  43 |     </div>
  44 | </div>
  45 |
```

Comment: You can't run the bind commands inside the methods that needs to be bound. The first two lines of toggleShow should be moved to the constructor. I am not sure this is the cause of your bug, but it definitely have to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `&&` after `this.state.show`.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you want to conditionally render based on the state, right?

In this case, the code should be something like this:

```
{
  this.state.show &&
  ( 
    <ul className="NavBar">
      <Dropdown/>    
      <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Host Your Space</Link></li>
      <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">About Us</Link></li>
      <li className="RightNav"><Link to0="/">Contact Us</Link></li>
      <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Sign Up</Link></li>
      <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Login</Link></li>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: Question What does the && do?